# Simple donation for app android app

Tags: android, payment, donations

I'd like to implement donation system for my [MPC Remote app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kdombrovsky.mpcremote). Since I live in Ukraine I can neither make a donation version nor accept donations via PayPal. I've also tried MoneyBookers which is a lot of hassle.

Does anybody know a simple payment system I could use?

Comment: Did you consider selling a second, paid version of the APP? Or is Google Checkout also no option to you?

Comment: Google Checkout doesn't work for users from Ukraine yet.

Comment: I see. That way you could either wait for Google Checkout to catch up with Ukraine or friendly ask for people to send you cash using normal mail? :-) Just a idea.

Comment: I'm waiting more than a year now :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting for long time to buy (yes, true) apps from within China. Everytime have to go to HK to buy apps. Horrible. :-( Maybe the "mail a donation" thing works if people love your app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a last case alternative could be to use In-App billing with a lot of pre-defined unmanaged products, symbolizing different donation-amounts. The donator then selects an amount from a "product" list and performs the "donation". One obvious drawback is that Google collects 30% of the "donation".